# customize rails url with username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I want to copy the twitter profile page and have a url with a username "http://www.my-app.com/username" and while I can manually type this into the address bar and navigate to the profile page I can't link to the custom URL.

I think the problem is in the routes - here's the code in my routes.rb

```
map.connect '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Also, I have `Question` and `Answer` models and I want to link to them with the customized URL like so:

http://www.my-app.com/username/question/answer/2210

Comment: You don't need to frame it better, just be more concise

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your route. Just remember to define it at the end, after defining all other routes. I would also recommend using RESTful routes and only if you want to have better looking URLs use named routes. Don't use `map.connect`. Here's some [good reading about Rails routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Here's how this could look:

```
map.resources :questions, :path_prefix => '/:username' do |question|
  question.resources :answers
end

map.resources :users

map.user '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Just a draft you can extend.

Answer (score 4):

To create urls you need to define `to_param` method for your user model ([read here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002325)).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param 
    username
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions is old but it will help someone.

You could try the below. I've used it in a rails 4 project and all seems to be working great. The reason for the `as: :admin` is I also had a `resources posts` outside of this scope. It will add a `admin` to the helper calls e.g. `admin_posts_path`

```
scope ":username", module: 'admin', as: :admin do
  get '', to: 'profiles#show'
  resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used like this

In View part

portfolio.user.name,:id =>portfolio) %>

and in rout.rb

map.show_portfolio "portfolios/:username", :action => 'show_portfolio', :controller => 'portfolios'