# Routing to profile page by username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking

I am working on a social media site and I am having a problem with routing.

Every user has a profile page like facebook and this is the root I use:

```
get 'profile(/:id)' => 'profiles#show'
```

So, when the URL is like this: www.sitename.com/profile/1 it opens up the page belongs to user with id 1. But, I also want users to be able to use their usernames in url without /profile/. So it is gonna be like facebook.

For example: www.sitename.com/handsomeboy69

How can I do this in routing? Because, rails may think that username passed in URL is a page name.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [username in url with rails routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269885/username-in-url-with-rails-routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. This is the route I used:

```
  get ':username' => 'profiles#show'
```

In the controller I used this statement:

```
if params.has_key?(:username)
  @profile = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
elsif params.has_key?(:id)
  @profile = User.find(params[:id])
else

end
```

else statement at the end is empty, I am gonna use that area to print out error message saying that profile cannot be found.

and most important part is that this routing should be at the end of the file.

Comment: you might also want to consider using the friendly_id gem. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: @moeabdol : Using this answer's approach, wouldn't you need to code some additional logic that ensures that nobody creates a username that matches any of your routes that potentially exist and are valid (currently and also after future updates), such as : `/users` or `/products` or `/items`? And would the friendly_id prevent that issue?